# How to serve flask app through nginx using gunicorn on a custom domain?

Tags: nginx, dns

Im trying to run a flask app on nginx through gunicorn using these instructions: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-flask-applications-with-gunicorn-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-18-04

In accordance with that tutorial, I have my two A records - one blank one and one for www on my domain pointing to my ip address.

I have a flask app and when I run it with `gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:5000 wsgi:app` for instance I can see it on :5000.

Now the problem comes when I try and set it up with gunicorn as a service on my own custom domain.

This is my /etc/systemd/system/myproject.service:

```
[Unit]
Description=Gunicorn instance to serve myproject
After=network.target

[Service]
User=root
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/srv/myproject
Environment="PATH=/myproject/myprojectenv/bin"
ExecStart=/srv/myproject/myprojectenv/bin/gunicorn --workers 3 --bind unix:myproject.sock -m 007 wsgi:app

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

And I start it with `sudo systemctl start myproject`

Then in `/etc/nginx/sites-available/myproject`

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name sweatt.app www.sweatt.app;

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/srv/myproject/myproject.sock;
    }
}
```

Now this one is the tricky one to me because when I switch sweatt.app to my ip, the ip successfully serves the flask app. However when I use the actual domains - sweatt.app and www.sweatt.app, it serves:

[image]

And when I try the old ip it actually gives the "welcome to nginx" landing page as though that ip is allowed but its just not serving the flask app through gunicorn.

So I have a few questions.

1. Why isn't this working
2. How do I get it to work
3. Whats the deal with those A records? Why would that tutorial tell me to make A records instead of a CNAME and alias record like I usually do? Is this the preferred way to serve a custom domain now?
4. what should that 3rd line in my nginx sites-available conf file look like? Is this the domain I eventually serve? Or the ip that the DNS is redirecting to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a .conf file at /etc/nginx/conf.d/ with the following content.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.yourdomain.com;

    access_log /..../access.log;
    error_log /..../error.log;

    location / {
        proxy_pass         http://127.0.0.1:5000/;
        proxy_redirect     off;
        proxy_set_header   Host             $host;
        proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
}
```

Comment: what are you saying? Are you saying I should use this sites-available file instead?

Comment: is this in place of /etc/nginx/sites-available? Do I keep that one as well?

Comment: I just created a .conf file at /etc/nginx/conf.d/ folder. I don't remember why but using sites-available didnt work to me. Once you modified your .conf file you have to reload the changes with /etc/init.d/nginx reload